# Куча непонятных ошибок

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ошибки:
[image]

```
#include "core.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

//socket define's
#define BUFLEN 50000
#define IP "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"  //айпи 
#define PORT 80

psHTTPBody sendHTTPmsg(psHTTPBody msg, bool bLoadContent){
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService; 

    string strBuf=" "; 
    //перенос после заголовков
    strBuf=msg->strHeader+"\r\n\r\n";
    //если есть тело запрса, то добавить его
    if (msg->bIsContent) 
        strBuf+=msg->strContent;
    char *sendbuf=new char[strBuf.length() + 1];
    strcpy(sendbuf, strBuf.c_str());

    //принимать сюда
    char recvbuf[BUFLEN];
    ZeroMemory(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    int recvbuflen = BUFLEN;
  
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( IP );
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Connect to server.
    connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    
    // Send an initial buffer
    send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);

    //буфер для return
    static sHTTPBody sHTTPreq;
    sHTTPreq.strHeader="";
    sHTTPreq.strContent="";
    sHTTPreq.bIsContent=FALSE;

    //получение заголовов
    do{
        ZeroMemory(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
        iResult=recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, BUFLEN, 0);
        sHTTPreq.strHeader+=recvbuf;
    }while (sHTTPreq.strHeader.find("\r\n\r\n")==std::string::npos);
    
    
    
    //получение тела (если потребовано)
    if (bLoadContent){
        sHTTPreq.bIsContent=TRUE;
        do{ 
            ZeroMemory(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
            iResult=recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, BUFLEN, 0);
            sHTTPreq.strContent+=recvbuf;
        }while (iResult!=0);
    };
    
    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    delete [] sendbuf;

    return &sHTTPreq;
};
string GetValue(string src, string mask){
    //strMaskBeg - маска до %VALUE%, чтобы совершить поиск
    string strMaskBeg=mask.substr(0, mask.find("%VALUE%"));
    //strMaskEnd - маска после %VALUE%
    string strMaskEnd=mask.substr(mask.find("%VALUE%")+strlen("%VALUE"), mask.length() ); 
    //iValueStart - начало запрашваемого значения в src
    int iValueStart=src.find(strMaskBeg) + strMaskBeg.length();
    //iValueEnd - индекс конца значения
    int iValueEnd=src.find(strMaskEnd,iValueStart);
    //iLen - длина значения
    int iLen=iValueEnd-iValueStart+1;
    
    return src.substr(iValueStart, iLen);
};
```

Что делать?? Помогите!

## UPD

core.h:

```
#pragma once

struct sHTTPBody{
    std::string strHeader;
    bool bIsContent;
    std::string strContent;
};
typedef sHTTPBody* psHTTPBody;
psHTTPBody sendHTTPmsg(psHTTPBody msg, bool bLoadContent);

//GetValue() mask's
#define MASK_PHPSESS "PHPSESS=%VALUE%;"
#define MASK_PIK_USERFORM_NAME "name=\"username_%VALUE%\""
#define MASK_PIK_PASSFORM_NAME "name=\"password_%VALUE%\""
std::string GetValue(std::string src, std::string mask);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с строки

```
 string strBuf=" ";
```

на первый взгляд - безобидная строка. Но видимо у Вас там ещё где то этот тип объявлен и компилятор не может его угадать. Поэтому, как всегда - лучше писать `std::string`.

Дальше нужно проверить типы `sHTTPBody` и `psHTTPBody`. Второй должен быть указателем на первый. И этот тип должен иметь поле `strHeader` с типом (скорее всего) `std::string`.

Большая половина остальных ошибок выходит с этих, поэтому сложно так сходу их отделить.

Comment: @KoVadim, хм, что же, мне всегда теперь писать std:string ?

Comment: @KoVadim, не помогло :(

Comment: @KoVadim, опять куча ошибок, но самая странная это "string не является членом std". Это как?

Comment: раз оно не является членом std, значит там бардак (я имею ввиду Ваш код). Показывайте "core.h"

Comment: после `#pragma once` добавьте необходимые include - как минимум `<string>`.